# Need to use jqueryui accordion, but it has been redefined by a second library

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

**ISSUE:**  I have situation where jquery ui is loaded and after the jquery ui library is loaded, a custom library is loaded.

This custom library defines an accordion for jquery, thus overwriting the jquery ui accordion.

**QUESTION:**   Is their something I could do in document.ready to define another accordion based off of the jquery ui accordion?   Then use this new accordion?  Or is their a way to directly call the jquery ui accordion?

The following code obviously calls the second libraries accordion...

```
$("selector").accordion
```

I can see the accordion is defined by doing the following in a browser debug console...

```
jQuery.ui.accordion
```

but I don't see how I can call it.

I don't have access to the main template for the site,  so  I can't modify the order of libraries loading.  Also,  the accordion from the second library is used across the site and it does NOT function at all like the jquery accordion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this:

<s>$.fn.uiAccordion = $.ui.accordion;</s>

```
$.widget.bridge('uiAccordion', $.ui.accordion);
```

Call like so:

```
$('selector').uiAccordion();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f6Lhh/1/)

Comment: I'm getting the error - 

Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method '_createWidget'

Comment: sounds like more than just the `accordion` namespace is being mucked with. Are you sure you have all the necessary jQuery UI scripts loaded?

Comment: What you identified makes sense.  But I tried it using a test site, just including jquery and jquery ui and I get the same error.

Comment: See update; you need to use jQuery UI's `bridge` method to register the function. Good question; I did not previously know about this!

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me :-).   Your solution worked great.

Comment: What a joke :(,  sorry that happened.